# "Content-Type not allowed" while uploading an SVG file, that is in the allowed whitelist

Tags: file-upload, svg, struts2, mime-types, struts2-convention-plugin

> **IMPORTANT: The following problem has been fixed in Struts version `2.3.24`**.
>
> From that version on, there is no need to escape any character.
>
> Read more: [JIRA Issue WW-4457](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4457).

---

I've configured the Struts2 FileUpload Interceptor to allow a whitelist of Content-Types.

This works correctly with any file matching the Content-Type specified, but **it doesn't work with `SVG` files**, which [have MIME media type `image/svg+xml`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/mimereg.html).

Using this configuration:

```java
@Action(value = "upload", 
    interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef( 
        value = "defaultStack",
        params = { "fileUpload.allowedTypes" , "application/pdf,"
                                             + "image/jpeg,"
                                             + "image/gif,"
                                             + "image/png,"
                                             + "image/svg+xml"
                  }))
```

and uploading a valid SVG file, I get the error message defined by the `struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed` property:

> Content-Type not allowed: {0} "{1}" "{2}" {3}

where `{3}` is the Content-Type that the user is trying to upload;

Then for example:

> Content-Type not allowed: myFile "Sample.svg" "upload__123__456__78.tmp" **image/svg+xml**

That is *exactly* the same Content-Type I defined in the `allowedTypes` whitelist.

Note that I use the `regex` Pattern Matcher, enabled with the following constant in struts.xml :

```xml
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher"  value="regex" />
```

Why isn't it working, and how to make it work ?

Comment: Have you changed default pattern matcher? For `regex` perhaps?

Comment: Definitely ! Adding to the question now, thank you

Comment: @AleksandrM feel free to answer with additional details about the pattern matcher and I'll upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fileUpload` interceptor uses `PatternMatcher` to check for allowed mime types. By default S2 uses `WildcardHelper` pattern matcher which will work with `image/svg+xml`.

By changing default pattern matcher to `regex` the `fileUpload` interceptor starts checking allowed types with regular expressions. And `+` is a special character in [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), so it must be escaped like that `image/svg\\+xml` in order to work.

Note: Changing default pattern matcher in this case introduces unexpected behavior and maybe should be reported as a bug.

Comment: Accepted your answer because of the analysis that is missing in mine. Will you report it as a bug ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Can you test with 2.3.22 snapshot to see if it works for you - [WW-4457](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4457?focusedCommentId=14350938&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14350938).

Comment: Waiting the release version for a final test

Comment: @AndreaLigios: `2.3.24` is out.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: It isn't on the homepage yet, but it will be soon. http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.struts|struts2-core|2.3.24|jar

Answer (score 1):

**The `+` symbol in the MIME is the culprit.**

It is somehow reserved, and hence it needs to be escaped; since with Convention plugin it is inside a String, the escaping backslash needs to be escaped too.

**Using `image/svg\\+xml` works like a charm:**

```
params = { "fileUpload.allowedTypes" ,    "application/pdf,"
                                        + "image/jpeg,"
                                        + "image/gif,"
                                        + "image/png,"
                                        + "image/svg\\+xml"
```

I'm not sure whether this is needed with the standard XML-based configuration too.